# The Bill Tush Show

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Tush (also known as [The Bill Tush Show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tush_(TV_series))) was an American late-night television sketch comedy and variety show developed for Bill Tush and directed by R. T. Williams.

Can anyone explain to me why the show was simply cobbled-together mixed-up crap?

> This is not a rant—in fact, living in Britain as I do, I have never seen the show. It is a genuine puzzle. Please explain all three elements of the show that I have mentioned. How can they be used together in a logical way to provide the answer?

Hint

> The link I gave was for interest only and to demonstrate that it was a real show. You can ignore any information gained by following the link. All the necessary information is given in the visible part of the question.

Comment: FINALLY. A puzzle with *clued* anagramming and a good surface reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take some crap:

> "Bullshit"

Mix it up:

> B u ll sh i t -> B i ll t u sh

Cobble it together:

> Bill tush

Comment: Yes, I saw the operations happening in exactly the reverse order to the way you specified but you have all the elements, so answer accepted.